# Drawing cards without replacement

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> $2$ cards are drawn from a standard deck of $52$ playing cards. How many different $2$-card hands are possible if the drawing is done without replacement?

I was not able to figure it out so someone please help me with these questions thank you and I have tried to use the formula but I keep hitting a dead end.

Comment: Would you please add what have you tried so far?

Comment: Which formula did you try to use?  You'll get the most out of this site if you tell us what you've tried, so we can explain your mistakes or misconceptions.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

How many different possibilities do you have for the first card you drawn?

How many different possibilities do you have for the second card drawn?

When you figure out these two think that for each of the possible outcomes for the first card you will have all the possible outcomes for the second card, this is called the product rule, which may hint on what you have to do with these numbers.

Hope this helped

If you have any questions just ask in the comments,

EDIT: I made a mistake which is quite common in combinatorics, namely I overcounted, lucky us N.F.Taussig (another user) is always on his toes to help us with minor or major oversights (thank you for that) and even luckier us we overcounted with a whole factor of two so the result you get must be divided by $2$.

Comment: This is not quite right.  You count each hand twice.  If you first pick $\color{red}{7\diamondsuit}$ and then pick $5\clubsuit$, you obtain the same hand as if you first pick $5\clubsuit$ and then pick $\color{red}{7\diamondsuit}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thank you for pointing that out, I edited the answer. Those  pesky overcounts!